# Set target to new not working in master page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, master-pages

I have Help menu with two links in dropdown. I need to set target of those two links to "new". I tried putting the javascript in document.ready and window.onload, still that didnt help.

When i execute below code in console it works fine, but when i put this in master page. It is not working. For the time being i am hardcoding 11.

```
$('ul .dynamic a').eq(11).attr('target','new')
```

Please suggest where on which event i place this piece of code in my master page

Comment: Use `.attr('target', '_blank')` instead of `new`.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you show full code?